# get_stylesheet_uri returns wrong path

Tags: css, wp-enqueue-style, theme-roots

I am using the roots theme. Inside scripts.php, the stylesheets are loaded using the wp_enqueue_style-function.

```
  wp_enqueue_style('roots_bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/bootstrap.css', false, null);
  wp_enqueue_style('roots_bootstrap_responsive', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css', array('roots_bootstrap'), null);
  wp_enqueue_style('roots_app', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/app.css', false, null);
```

I tried to add my own stylesheet (style.css, it can be found directly inside the template folder) the same way:

```
  wp_enqueue_style('fsc', get_stylesheet_uri(), false, null);
```

This is the output:

```
<link href="/wordpress/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Of course this doesnt work. Same for get_template part or blog_info('stylesheet_url') What's interesting is, that the other paths are wrong, too:

```
<link href="/wordpress/assets/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

But the bootstrap stylesheets are loaded however. How is that possible?

This is the htaccess:

```
            # BEGIN HTML5 Boilerplate

            ###
            ### This contains the HTML5 Boilerplate .htaccess that can be found at:
            ### https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs/blob/master/apache/.htaccess
            ###
            ### Added:
            ###   Block access to WordPress files that reveal version information.
            ###
            ### Removed:
            ###   Expires headers:      Use W3 Total Cache
            ###   ETag removal:         Use W3 Total Cache
            ###   Start rewrite engine: Handled by WordPress
            ###   Suppress/force www:   Handled by WordPress
            ###   Custom 404 page:      Handled by WordPress
            ###
            ### Commmented out by default:
            ###   Options -MultiViews:  Causes a server 500 error on most shared hosts
            ###
            ### Anytime you update this file the .htaccess file in the root of your
            ### WordPress install is automatically updated with the changes whenever
            ### the permalinks are flushed or set (see lib/htaccess.php)
            ###



            # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
            # Better website experience for IE users
            # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

            # Force the latest IE version, in various cases when it may fall back to IE7 mode
            #  github.com/rails/rails/commit/123eb25#commitcomment-118920
            # Use ChromeFrame if it's installed for a better experience for the poor IE folk

            <IfModule mod_headers.c>
              Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=edge,chrome=1"
              # mod_headers can't match by content-type, but we don't want to send this header on *everything*...
              <FilesMatch "\.(appcache|crx|css|eot|gif|htc|ico|jpe?g|js|m4a|m4v|manifest|mp4|oex|oga|ogg|ogv|otf|pdf|png|safariextz|svg|svgz|ttf|vcf|webm|webp|woff|xml|xpi)$">
                Header unset X-UA-Compatible
              </FilesMatch>
            </IfModule>


            # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
            # Cross-domain AJAX requests
            # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

            # Serve cross-domain Ajax requests, disabled by default.
            # enable-cors.org
            # code.google.com/p/html5security/wiki/CrossOriginRequestSecurity

            #  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            #    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
            #  </IfModule>


            # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
            # CORS-enabled images (@crossorigin)
            # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

            # Send CORS headers if browsers request them; enabled by default for images.
            # developer.mozilla.org/en/CORS_Enabled_Image
            # blog.chromium.org/2011/07/using-cross-domain-images-in-webgl-and.html
            # hacks.mozilla.org/2011/11/using-cors-to-load-webgl-textures-from-cross-domain-images/
            # wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Reviews/crossoriginAttribute

            <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
              <IfModule mod_headers.c>
                # mod_headers, y u no match by Content-Type?!
                <FilesMatch "\.(gif|ico|jpe?g|png|svg|svgz|webp)$">
                  SetEnvIf Origin ":" IS_CORS
                  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=IS_CORS
                </FilesMatch>
              </IfModule>
            </IfModule>


            # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
            # Webfont access
            # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

            # Allow access from all domains for webfonts.
            # Alternatively you could only whitelist your
            # subdomains like "subdomain.example.com".

            <IfModule mod_headers.c>
              <FilesMatch "\.(eot|font.css|otf|ttc|ttf|woff)$">
                Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
              </FilesMatch>
            </IfModule>


            # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
            # Proper MIME type for all files
            # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

            # JavaScript
            #   Normalize to standard type (it's sniffed in IE anyways)
            #   tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4329#section-7.2
            AddType application/javascript         js jsonp
            AddType application/json               json

            # Audio
            AddType audio/mp4                      m4a f4a f4b
            AddType audio/ogg                      oga ogg

            # Video
            AddType video/mp4                      mp4 m4v f4v f4p
            AddType video/ogg                      ogv
            AddType video/webm                     webm
            AddType video/x-flv                    flv

            # SVG
            #   Required for svg webfonts on iPad
            #   twitter.com/FontSquirrel/status/14855840545
            AddType     image/svg+xml              svg svgz
            AddEncoding gzip                       svgz

            # Webfonts
            AddType application/font-woff          woff
            AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject  eot
            AddType application/x-font-ttf         ttf ttc
            AddType font/opentype                  otf

            # Assorted types
            AddType application/octet-stream            safariextz
            AddType application/x-chrome-extension      crx
            AddType application/x-opera-extension       oex
            AddType application/x-shockwave-flash       swf
            AddType application/x-web-app-manifest+json webapp
            AddType application/x-xpinstall             xpi
            AddType application/xml                     rss atom xml rdf
            AddType image/webp                          webp
            AddType image/x-icon                        ico
            AddType text/cache-manifest                 appcache manifest
            AddType text/vtt                            vtt
            AddType text/x-component                    htc
            AddType text/x-vcard                        vcf


            # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
            # Allow concatenation from within specific js and css files
            # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

            # e.g. Inside of script.combined.js you could have
            #   <!--#include file="libs/jquery-1.5.0.min.js" -->
            #   <!--#include file="plugins/jquery.idletimer.js" -->
            # and they would be included into this single file.

            # This is not in use in the boilerplate as it stands. You may
            # choose to use this technique if you do not have a build process.

            #<FilesMatch "\.combined\.js$">
            #  Options +Includes
            #  AddOutputFilterByType INCLUDES application/javascript application/json
            #  SetOutputFilter INCLUDES
            #</FilesMatch>

            #<FilesMatch "\.combined\.css$">
            #  Options +Includes
            #  AddOutputFilterByType INCLUDES text/css
            #  SetOutputFilter INCLUDES
            #</FilesMatch>


            # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
            # Gzip compression
            # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

            <IfModule mod_deflate.c>

              # Force deflate for mangled headers developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/12/pushing-beyond-gzipping/
              <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
                <IfModule mod_headers.c>
                  SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
                  RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
                </IfModule>
              </IfModule>

              # Compress all output labeled with one of the following MIME-types
              # (for Apache versions below 2.3.7, you don't need to enable `mod_filter`
              # and can remove the `<IfModule mod_filter.c>` and `</IfModule>` lines as
              # `AddOutputFilterByType` is still in the core directives)
              <IfModule mod_filter.c>
                AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml \
                                              application/javascript \
                                              application/json \
                                              application/rss+xml \
                                              application/vnd.ms-fontobject \
                                              application/x-font-ttf \
                                              application/xhtml+xml \
                                              application/xml \
                                              font/opentype \
                                              image/svg+xml \
                                              image/x-icon \
                                              text/css \
                                              text/html \
                                              text/plain \
                                              text/x-component \
                                              text/xml
              </IfModule>

            </IfModule>


            # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
            # Prevent mobile network providers from modifying your site
            # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

            # The following header prevents modification of your code over 3G on some
            # European providers.
            # This is the official 'bypass' suggested by O2 in the UK.

            # <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            # Header set Cache-Control "no-transform"
            # </IfModule>


            # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
            # Stop screen flicker in IE on CSS rollovers
            # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

            # The following directives stop screen flicker in IE on CSS rollovers - in
            # combination with the "ExpiresByType" rules for images (see above).

            # BrowserMatch "MSIE" brokenvary=1
            # BrowserMatch "Mozilla/4.[0-9]{2}" brokenvary=1
            # BrowserMatch "Opera" !brokenvary
            # SetEnvIf brokenvary 1 force-no-vary


            # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
            # Set Keep-Alive Header
            # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

            # Keep-Alive allows the server to send multiple requests through one
            # TCP-connection. Be aware of possible disadvantages of this setting. Turn on
            # if you serve a lot of static content.

            # <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            #   Header set Connection Keep-Alive
            # </IfModule>


            # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
            # Cookie setting from iframes
            # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

            # Allow cookies to be set from iframes (for IE only)
            # If needed, specify a path or regex in the Location directive.

            # <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            #   Header set P3P "policyref=\"/w3c/p3p.xml\", CP=\"IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT\""
            # </IfModule>


            # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
            # Built-in filename-based cache busting
            # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

            # If you're not using the build script to manage your filename version revving,
            # you might want to consider enabling this, which will route requests for
            # `/css/style.20110203.css` to `/css/style.css`.

            # To understand why this is important and a better idea than all.css?v1231,
            # please refer to the bundled documentation about `.htaccess`.

            # <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            #   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            #   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            #   RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(js|css|png|jpg|gif)$ $1.$3 [L]
            # </IfModule>


            # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
            # Prevent SSL cert warnings
            # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

            # Rewrite secure requests properly to prevent SSL cert warnings, e.g. prevent
            # https://www.example.com when your cert only allows https://secure.example.com

            # <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            #   RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443
            #   RewriteRule ^ https://example-domain-please-change-me.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
            # </IfModule>


            # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
            # Force client-side SSL redirection
            # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

            # If a user types "example.com" in her browser, the above rule will redirect her
            # to the secure version of the site. That still leaves a window of opportunity
            # (the initial HTTP connection) for an attacker to downgrade or redirect the
            # request. The following header ensures that browser will **only** connect to
            # your server via HTTPS, regardless of what users type in the address bar.

            # <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            #   Header set Strict-Transport-Security max-age=16070400;
            # </IfModule>


            # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
            # Prevent 404 errors for non-existing redirected folders
            # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

            # without -MultiViews, Apache will give a 404 for a rewrite if a folder of the
            # same name does not exist.
            # webmasterworld.com/apache/3808792.htm

            # Options -MultiViews


            # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
            # UTF-8 encoding
            # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

            # Use UTF-8 encoding for anything served text/plain or text/html
            AddDefaultCharset utf-8

            # Force UTF-8 for a number of file formats
            AddCharset utf-8 .atom .css .js .json .rss .vtt .xml


            # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
            # A little more security
            # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

            # To avoid displaying the exact version number of Apache being used, add the
            # following to httpd.conf (it will not work in .htaccess):
            # ServerTokens Prod

            # "-Indexes" will have Apache block users from browsing folders without a
            # default document Usually you should leave this activated, because you
            # shouldn't allow everybody to surf through every folder on your server (which
            # includes rather private places like CMS system folders).
            <IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
              Options -Indexes
            </IfModule>

            # Block access to "hidden" directories or files whose names begin with a
            # period. This includes directories used by version control systems such as
            # Subversion or Git.
            <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
              RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
              RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
              RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]
            </IfModule>

            # Block access to backup and source files. These files may be left by some
            # text/html editors and pose a great security danger, when anyone can access
            # them.
            <FilesMatch "(\.(bak|config|dist|fla|inc|ini|log|psd|sh|sql|swp)|~)$">
              Order allow,deny
              Deny from all
              Satisfy All
            </FilesMatch>

            # If your server is not already configured as such, the following directive
            # should be uncommented in order to set PHP's register_globals option to OFF.
            # This closes a major security hole that is abused by most XSS (cross-site
            # scripting) attacks. For more information: http://php.net/register_globals
            #
            # IF REGISTER_GLOBALS DIRECTIVE CAUSES 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERRORS:
            #
            # Your server does not allow PHP directives to be set via .htaccess. In that
            # case you must make this change in your php.ini file instead. If you are
            # using a commercial web host, contact the administrators for assistance in
            # doing this. Not all servers allow local php.ini files, and they should
            # include all PHP configurations (not just this one), or you will effectively
            # reset everything to PHP defaults. Consult www.php.net for more detailed
            # information about setting PHP directives.

            # php_flag register_globals Off

            # Rename session cookie to something else, than PHPSESSID
            # php_value session.name sid

            # Disable magic quotes (This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.)
            # php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off

            # Do not show you are using PHP
            # Note: Move this line to php.ini since it won't work in .htaccess
            # php_flag expose_php Off

            # Level of log detail - log all errors
            # php_value error_reporting -1

            # Write errors to log file
            # php_flag log_errors On

            # Do not display errors in browser (production - Off, development - On)
            # php_flag display_errors Off

            # Do not display startup errors (production - Off, development - On)
            # php_flag display_startup_errors Off

            # Format errors in plain text
            # Note: Leave this setting 'On' for xdebug's var_dump() output
            # php_flag html_errors Off

            # Show multiple occurrence of error
            # php_flag ignore_repeated_errors Off

            # Show same errors from different sources
            # php_flag ignore_repeated_source Off

            # Size limit for error messages
            # php_value log_errors_max_len 1024

            # Don't precede error with string (doesn't accept empty string, use whitespace if you need)
            # php_value error_prepend_string " "

            # Don't prepend to error (doesn't accept empty string, use whitespace if you need)
            # php_value error_append_string " "

            # Increase cookie security
            <IfModule mod_php5.c>
              php_value session.cookie_httponly true
            </IfModule>

            # END HTML5 Boilerplate

            # BEGIN WordPress
            <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteBase /wordpress/
            RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
            RewriteRule ^assets/css/(.*) /wordpress/wp-content/themes/fsc/assets/css/$1 [QSA,L]
            RewriteRule ^assets/js/(.*) /wordpress/wp-content/themes/fsc/assets/js/$1 [QSA,L]
            RewriteRule ^assets/img/(.*) /wordpress/wp-content/themes/fsc/assets/img/$1 [QSA,L]
            RewriteRule ^plugins/(.*) /wordpress/wp-content/plugins/$1 [QSA,L]
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
            </IfModule>

            # END WordPress
```

This is the htaccess.php, I was talking about:

```
<?php
/**
 * Add HTML5 Boilerplate's .htaccess via WordPress
 */
function roots_add_h5bp_htaccess($content) {
  global $wp_rewrite;
  $home_path = function_exists('get_home_path') ? get_home_path() : ABSPATH;
  $htaccess_file = $home_path . '.htaccess';
  $mod_rewrite_enabled = function_exists('got_mod_rewrite') ? got_mod_rewrite() : false;

  if ((!file_exists($htaccess_file) && is_writable($home_path) && $wp_rewrite->using_mod_rewrite_permalinks()) || is_writable($htaccess_file)) {
    if ($mod_rewrite_enabled) {
      $h5bp_rules = extract_from_markers($htaccess_file, 'HTML5 Boilerplate');
      if ($h5bp_rules === array()) {
        $filename = dirname(__FILE__) . '/h5bp-htaccess';
        return insert_with_markers($htaccess_file, 'HTML5 Boilerplate', extract_from_markers($filename, 'HTML5 Boilerplate'));
      }
    }
  }

  return $content;
}

if (current_theme_supports('h5bp-htaccess')) {
  add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'roots_add_h5bp_htaccess');
}
```

Comment: What is in your `.htaccess` file? Also, try switching themes and see if those functions work.

Comment: The theme has a file called h5bp-htaccess. Is that relevant? Or just the htaccess under wordpress/ or both?

Comment: Start with the normal `.htaccess` under `/wordpress/`

Comment: And theres a htaccess.php, which contains something with homepath and rewrite rules, I dont understand. I will post it above.

Comment: This post is starting to get too long, if neccessary, I will provide h5bp-htaccess.

Comment: It seems to contain the same.

Comment: If I switch themes, everything works fine.

Comment: What about `h5bp-htaccess`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8050/discussion-between-s-ha-dum-and-lord-mord)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you want [`get_stylesheet_uri`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_uri), which will return the *complete stylesheet URL* including `style.css`. You want [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri), which will give you the path up to the child/parent theme stylesheet directory but not the trailing `style.css`, and which is the function used by the Roots theme per the code you posted.

```
wp_enqueue_style('fsc', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/abcdefg.css', false, null);
```

I also notice that you didn't provide the actual stylesheet name so I tacked on `/abcdefg.css`.

It is interesting that the URLs are not absolute URLs. That could be a plugin, a theme, or some server module like Google's PageSpeed, [which will strip the domain like that.](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/mod_pagespeed/filter-trim-urls)

### The work-around !

Per a chat with Lord_Mort, we worked out that the Roots theme appears to be rewriting requests to either `/themes/` or `/wp-content/themes/` which makes it difficult to add stylesheets normally. Lord_Mort discovered that a path like `wp-content/beans/fsc/style.css` is not rewritten, so the workaround we came to is to is to use the same trick that Roots uses and add stylesheets to a non-standard location that will not be rewritten. Lord_Mort's decision was to use the same one Roots uses.

```
wp_enqueue_style('fsc', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/assets/css/style.css', false, null);
```

Without installing that theme I don't think I can debug and solve the issue more elegantly.

Comment: The stylesheets name is style.css. get_stylesheet_directory_uri() doesnt work either. It returns the same path.

Comment: If it is a plugin or theme, shouldnt it work for my url, too?

Comment: Sounds like a broken install, or your theme or a plugin is causing trouble. No, doesn't necessarily mean that what works for the Roots stylesheets will work for yours. It looks a bit like Roots has relativized the path to its directory, somehow. What should the full URL be?

Comment: wordpress/wp-content/themes/fsc/style.css

Comment: This answer helped me understand the difference btw `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` and `get_stylesheet_uri()`